# the usability of Ellipsis in specially in c

Tags: c

Hi i`m student and I want to know why using Ellipsis.
Cant you pass an arguments by using array and size?

I understand that using Ellipsis allow you to pass multi type arguments isn't their better solution.

The must discouraging that I understand that you cant really pass dynamically argument to Ellipsis. I mean that I want to use function that use Ellipsis with the same argument in my function which are Ellipsis(used)

By Ellipsis   i mean func(int arg, ...);

sorry if i didn't write the correct therms.

thanks for the help

Comment: It's called variadic function, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: Thanks I thought it called in diffrent way but I still dont understand why using it